# Understanding hosts file on Linux machines

Tags: linux, ip, hosts-file

When I read `/etc/hosts` on my Ubuntu machine, the first two lines are as follows:

```
ipAddr1 localhost
ipAddr2 nameOfMachine
```

Are these IP addresses characteristic to my machine or are they related to the network I am connected to? Also, it is possible to edit these, but isn’t the IP address hardware written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address on your machine is not connected to hardware and the first two lines you are showing are related to the way your machine is connected to your network. The only item related to networking that is in the hardware is the MAC address and that is a 100% different thing.

In general, an IP address is assigned when you connect the network interface to a network based on your system’s settings. So when you say this:

```
ipAddr1 localhost
ipAddr2 nameOfMachine
```

But the addresses would be something like this; using `123.456.789.1` as an example:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
123.456.789.1 nameOfMachine
```

The address `127.0.0.1` is a universally accepted standard for the `localhost` loopback address.  The `123.456.789.1` is the network address that was assigned to your machine when it got a network connection. And on a Linux machine, the way that is setup is via `/etc/network/interfaces` which you can view like so:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces
```

A fairly standard and basic setup for the `interfaces` file is something like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 123.456.789.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

That directly correlates to what you see in the `/etc/hosts`. The `face lo inet loopback` connects to what you see in the line `127.0.0.1   localhost` and the `face eth0 inet static` connects to the `123.456.789.1 nameOfMachine` line.

In general, you do not mess around with the `/etc/hosts` file. And you definitely do not change `127.0.0.1  localhost`. The `123.456.789.1 nameOfMachine` is something that might get self-assigned when a Linux is first installed on a machine and should stay there. That allows you to be on the host `nameOfMachine` and be able to do something like `ping nameOfMachine` without failure.

Answer (score 2):

They are placed there by the Ubuntu installer in response to what you enter for the hostname of the system.

The `/etc/hosts` file is possibly (and by default) used by your system's **DNS resolver** whenever an application wants do a DNS lookup.

Before DNS existed, each machine had a local hosts file, and would consult it to convert domain names into IP addresses.

Now, typically a request to a DNS server is performed, but the hosts file still exists, and if your system is configured to use it, it will look into this file for names before making an external DNS query.

Your machine's hostname appears for `127.0.0.1` in this file because an external DNS server will not know your local hostname, unless it cooperates with DHCP somehow (Microsoft AD/DHCP/DNS servers do this).  So, this is done so a DNS lookup for "localhost", or your computer hostname, will return a correct result.

[@Giacomo1968's answer](https://superuser.com/a/840934/167207) inspired me to add this: don't remove or change the localhost entries - UNLESS you change your hostname!  There's some programs out there that require your local hostname to resolve correctly (`exim4` being one of them).

And [@Hennes answer](https://superuser.com/a/840933/167207) is right, the IP address does not exist in hardware, only the MAC does.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no the IP address is not written in hardware. The MAC address is.

And yes, you can edit them.  You censored the actual IPs but I suspect that at least one of them is `127.0.0.1`, which you should not change. Many things depends on being able to reach the own computer 'sort of via the network'.

These calls to a computer can be to actual other computers, or they can loop back to the computer itself.  For efficiency reason it is quite nice if you do not actually need to send these via the network when they are intended for yourself, so we use a loopback interface. To this loopback interface we assigned the range `127.0.0.0/8`, usually implemented as `127.0.0.1`.

To recap:

- Yes, you can edit them.
- No, you should not edit some of them.